# What good algorithms are there for shuffling (scrambling) 1 to n objects?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, random, poker

I have seen many algorithms for generating random numbers, so I wondered what common algorithms exist for scrambling a set of given numbers (or objects).

The numbers or objects need not be in any particular order (e.g. $1,2,3, ..., n$).

There are several online *shuffling* programs and some are part of common programs such as Excel. So I am interested in:

1. well-known shuffling algorithms
2. how they compare to the expected number of fixed points (i.e. *rencontres numbers*, I believe)
3. any known issues with such algorithms
4. any known comparisons, e.g. Excel's number shuffler versus Python's

Comment: The [Knuth shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is good and easy to implement.

Comment: Are there any constraints on the shuffling?  Because otherwise, Fisher-Yates is both optimal (in some sense) and very boring. :-)

Comment: Well, let's assume all numbers being shuffled are distinct (e.g. a pack of cards).

Answer (score 3):

[Fisher Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is a proper (uniform) shuffle and efficient. Uniform in that all permutations are created equally.

It has been around since 1938 but a few poker sites got it wrong and it was exploited.

```
-- To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
for i from n−1 downto 1 do
     j ← random integer such that 0 ≤ j ≤ i
     exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

There are n! permutations and Fisher mimics that.

Issues are if random is not random.  Don't create a new random with each shuffle and shuffle from the prior shuffle (not a clean deck).  Unless they knew the initial seed they could not pick up a pattern (without a LOT of hands - like approaching infinity).

A common problem is actually too many permutations and some are produced more than others. For example, swap every element with every other element (no j ≤ i).

Another problem is not allow a card to stay in its current position. If ace spades came off first then it cannot come off first next time.

Comment: See *legendary* Robert Sedgewick present this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54rMYC2pEtw (no proof)

Comment: I'd say the last paragraph is largely down to implementation details of the RNG and probably better for elsewhere. One _very_ common mistake that's made in the algorithm itself, though, is to choose $j$ randomly between $0$ and $n$, rather than $0$ and $i$; this leads to a non-uniform distribution on the set of permutations and to some permutations being much more likely than others; see https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6519/ for some of the details on this.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Shuffle from the last does not have to do (directly)  with random and it does make it harder to pick up any patterns.

Comment: @paparazzo It is absolutely a randomness issue. If your RNG is 'perfect' then shuffling from a perfectly sorted starting position is exactly equivalent to shuffling from the last shuffled position.  (And if your RNG isn't perfect, then there's really no guarantee that shuffling from a previously-shuffled deck will lead to fewer patterns than shuffling from a 'fresh' deck.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Not going to debate with. That is a big if.  Perfect random is an illusion.  Shuffle from a shuffle is going to be harder to pick up a pattern. They only get to observe part of the shuffle.